# StartTls, ApacheDS Problem

Tags: ldap, apacheds, starttls

I have been struggling in getting Start Tls to work for my ldap server. I have configured a keystore and password in a spring context file. My configuration seems to work for SSL but Star Tls is causing goosebumps. I have added StarTlsHandler as an ExtendedOperationHandler in wrapper of my LDAP Server. Do I need to configure anything else as well.

I am using JDK 1.6.0_15

Keystore and password are hard coded at the moment, they seem OK when I use SSL or debug.

I am using JLdap Client to test my implementation.

Here is a code snippet I have added for Handler: 
ldapServer.setKeystoreFile("C:/jdk/dgekey.ks");
ldapServer.setCertificatePassword("secret");
ldapServer.addExtendedOperationHandler(new StartTlsHandler());

Below you can see stack trace on the server side, client trace is further down:

2011-05-10 12:51:29,345 [rThread-4861-21] DEBUG [org.apache.directory.server.ldap.handlers.extended.StartTlsHandler] Setting LDAP Service
2011-05-10 12:51:29,345 [rThread-4861-21] DEBUG [org.apache.directory.server.ldap.handlers.extended.StartTlsHandler] provider = SUN version 1.6
2011-05-10 12:58:31,029 [rThread-4861-21] ERROR [org.apache.directory.server.core.security.CoreKeyStoreSpi] ERR_68 Failed on attempt to extract key.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ERR_436 Names used for principals must be normalized!
    at org.apache.directory.server.core.LdapPrincipal.(LdapPrincipal.java:76)
    at org.apache.directory.server.core.security.CoreKeyStoreSpi.getTlsEntry(CoreKeyStoreSpi.java:84)
    at org.apache.directory.server.core.security.CoreKeyStoreSpi.engineGetKey(CoreKeyStoreSpi.java:231)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:763)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SunX509KeyManagerImpl.(SunX509KeyManagerImpl.java:113)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509.engineInit(KeyManagerFactoryImpl.java:48)
    at javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.init(KeyManagerFactory.java:239)
    at org.apache.directory.server.ldap.handlers.extended.StartTlsHandler.setLdapServer(StartTlsHandler.java:170)
    at org.apache.directory.server.ldap.LdapServer.startNetwork(LdapServer.java:542)
    at org.apache.directory.server.ldap.LdapServer.start(LdapServer.java:446)
    at com..ldap.apacheds.LdapServerWrapper.afterPropertiesSet(LdapServerWrapper.java:103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1469)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1409)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:574)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5364)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:986)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:970)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:704)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1649)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1254)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.WebModuleDeployEventListener.moduleDeployed(WebModuleDeployEventListener.java:182)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.WebModuleDeployEventListener.moduleDeployed(WebModuleDeployEventListener.java:278)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.event.AdminEventMulticaster.invokeModuleDeployEventListener(AdminEventMulticaster.java:1005)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.event.AdminEventMulticaster.handleModuleDeployEvent(AdminEventMulticaster.java:992)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.event.AdminEventMulticaster.processEvent(AdminEventMulticaster.java:470)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.event.AdminEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(AdminEventMulticaster.java:182)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.server.core.DeploymentNotificationHelper.multicastEvent(DeploymentNotificationHelper.java:308)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.DeploymentServiceUtils.multicastEvent(DeploymentServiceUtils.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.ServerDeploymentTarget.sendStartEvent(ServerDeploymentTarget.java:298)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.ApplicationStartPhase.runPhase(ApplicationStartPhase.java:132)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.DeploymentPhase.executePhase(DeploymentPhase.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.PEDeploymentService.executePhases(PEDeploymentService.java:966)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.PEDeploymentService.start(PEDeploymentService.java:609)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.PEDeploymentService.start(PEDeploymentService.java:653)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.mbeans.ApplicationsConfigMBean.start(ApplicationsConfigMBean.java:773)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.MBeanHelper.invokeOperationInBean(MBeanHelper.java:390)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.MBeanHelper.invokeOperationInBean(MBeanHelper.java:373)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.config.BaseConfigMBean.invoke(BaseConfigMBean.java:477)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor15.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.util.proxy.ProxyClass.invoke(ProxyClass.java:90)
    at $Proxy1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.server.core.jmx.SunoneInterceptor.invoke(SunoneInterceptor.java:304)
    at com.sun.enterprise.interceptor.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:170)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.jmx.remote.server.callers.InvokeCaller.call(InvokeCaller.java:69)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.jmx.remote.server.MBeanServerRequestHandler.handle(MBeanServerRequestHandler.java:155)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.jmx.remote.server.servlet.RemoteJmxConnectorServlet.processRequest(RemoteJmxConnectorServlet.java:122)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.jmx.remote.server.servlet.RemoteJmxConnectorServlet.doPost(RemoteJmxConnectorServlet.java:193)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:315)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:287)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:94)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1093)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1093)
    at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(DefaultProcessorTask.java:666)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.doProcess(DefaultProcessorTask.java:597)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.process(DefaultProcessorTask.java:872)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.executeProcessorTask(DefaultReadTask.java:341)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:263)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:214)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:264)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.WorkerThreadImpl.run(WorkerThreadImpl.java:117)

****Client Trace via javax.net.debug=all;****

keyStore is : C:/jdk/cacerts
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
trustStore is: C:\jdk\cacerts
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=SwissSign Platinum CA - G2, O=SwissSign AG, C=CH
  Issuer:  CN=SwissSign Platinum CA - G2, O=SwissSign AG, C=CH
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x4eb200670c035d4f
  Valid from Wed Oct 25 10:36:00 CEST 2006 until Sat Oct 25 10:36:00 CEST 2036

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1288255192 bytes = { 100, 146, 27, 29, 47, 10, 97, 247, 253, 145, 49, 147, 239, 157, 90, 4, 34, 15, 99, 243, 191, 156, 251, 25, 64, 42, 210, 231 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }

---

[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 73
0000: 01 00 00 45 03 01 4D C9   37 D8 64 92 1B 1D 2F 0A  ...E..M.7.d.../.
0010: 61 F7 FD 91 31 93 EF 9D   5A 04 22 0F 63 F3 BF 9C  a...1...Z.".c...
0020: FB 19 40 2A D2 E7 00 00   1E 00 04 00 05 00 2F 00  ..@*........../.
0030: 33 00 32 00 0A 00 16 00   13 00 09 00 15 00 12 00  3.2.............
0040: 03 00 08 00 14 00 11 01   00                       .........
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 73
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 98
0000: 01 03 01 00 39 00 00 00   20 00 00 04 01 00 80 00  ....9... .......
0010: 00 05 00 00 2F 00 00 33   00 00 32 00 00 0A 07 00  ..../..3..2.....
0020: C0 00 00 16 00 00 13 00   00 09 06 00 40 00 00 15  ............@...
0030: 00 00 12 00 00 03 02 00   80 00 00 08 00 00 14 00  ................
0040: 00 11 4D C9 37 D8 64 92   1B 1D 2F 0A 61 F7 FD 91  ..M.7.d.../.a...
0050: 31 93 EF 9D 5A 04 22 0F   63 F3 BF 9C FB 19 40 2A  1...Z.".c.....@*
0060: D2 E7                                              ..
main, WRITE: SSLv2 client hello message, length = 98
main, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
Error: LDAPException: Could not negotiate a secure connection (91) Connect Error
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently TlsHandler can only read the certificate from the uid=admin,ou=system entry. Can you try after setting your certificate and keys to the appropriate attribute values of the admin entry (uid=admin,ou=system). I will try to fix this in the latest trunk. (Appreciate if you can file a bug report).

Comment: @kayyagri Thanks for the help. Where can I report this bug, I didn't find any link on ApacheDs sitr http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/1.5/downloads.html        
Secondly, how can I quickly fix this issue since I have deadline approaching in few days time

Comment: The entry uid=admin,ou=system has the attributes, privateKey, publicKey and certificate replace the existing values with the keys and certificate you have (you can use Apache Directory Studio to make it easier). You can report issue here [https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DIRSERVER]

Comment: Hi again @kayyagri and thanks for the reply,

I copied the default certificate present in ApacheDs server, generated a keystore from that certificate and provided path of this keystore to my ldap/spring context file. But still I get the same error. Certificate and keystore which work with standalone apacheDs do not work when I use them via my ldap implementation. 

Should I configure something else as well.